# Trying to open a python file using power shell but it brings up a list 'index out of range' error... but the items are not out of range?

Tags: powershell, indexing

```
PS C:\OIDv4_ToolKit> python convert_annotations.py
Currently in subdirectory: train
Converting annotations for class:  Vehicle registration plate
  0%|                                                                                          | 0/400 [00:00<?, ?it/s]0317.44 497.91974400000004 413.44 526.08

  0%|                                                                                          | 0/400 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OIDv4_ToolKit\convert_annotations.py", line 66, in <module>
    coords = np.asarray([float(labels[1]), float(labels[2]), float(labels[3]), float(labels[4])])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

python file: this is the error it refers to as line 66 (Line 7 here)

```
with open(filename) as f:
                            for line in f:
                                for class_type in classes:
                                    line = line.replace(class_type, str(classes.get(class_type)))
                                print(line)
                               
                                labels = line.split()
                                                               
                                coords = np.asarray([float(labels[1]), float(labels[2]), float(labels[3]), float(labels[4])])
                                coords = convert(filename_str, coords)
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a PowerShell issue; the python interpreter looks like it is being run correctly. I suggest adding the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag to your question to get the right people involved.

Having located the [source](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/OIDv4_ToolKit/blob/36d500d20e22e01904e672b8e96ed50b15e39aea/convert_annotations.py#L58-L64), it seems as if some of the text files in the following directory aren't in the format expected by `convert_annotations.py`:

```
C:\OIDv4_ToolKit\OID\Dataset\train\Vehicle registration plate\Label\
```

You can verify this with:

```py
print("labels length =", len(labels))
```

after the `line.split()` method. If you get a length of `1`, it is likely the items on a line somewhere aren't separated with whitespace, for example with commas. You can also inspect the files manually to determine the format. To find them, you can use:

```py
print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename))
```

inside the the `for` loop, which is on Line 54 in the source I linked above. Note also that the [string `split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method supports a custom separator as the first argument, should the files be in a different format.

Comment: One more note - please use code fences when posting code or traces/logs. You can read more at [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you don't put the class name in classes.txt
The class name should be same in classes.txt as downloaded class.